# Is it possible to setup continuous integration in Azure from GitHub for a web app based on .NET Core Angular template?

Tags: c#, angular, azure, .net-core

I built a web app based on .NET Core Angular template, when you execute `dotnet new angular` command.
We all know the folder structure of this template, where the client app sits in ClientApp subfolder.

I am usually deploying this app to Azure using FTP copy: I built the app with `dotnet publish -c Release` command, which creates a deployment version in `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\` folder. I FTP copy contents of that folder over to Azure and everything works fine.

I was trying to set up continuous integration in Azure with my GitHub repository, steps are very simple, the link between my Azure web app and the GitHub repository created with no problems. Now, when I commit new changes to my repository, I can see that deployment was triggered automatically in Azure, so far so good.

However, when I reload my Azure app in the browser I don't see any changes.

If in my local `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\` folder the content for deployment looks like this:

`ClientApp\
wwwroot\
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
Homepage.dll
Homepage.pdb
Homepage.deps.json
Homepage.runtimeconfig.json
Homepage.Views.dll
Homepage.Views.pdb
HtmlAgilityPack.dll
System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll
System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument.dll
web.config`

then in Azure, after the continuous deployment ran, the content looks like this:

`.vscode/
ClientApp/
Controllers/
obj/
Pages/
Properties/
wwwroot/
.gitignore
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
Homepage.csproj
Homepage.dll
Homepage.pdb
Homepage.deps.json
Homepage.runtimeconfig.json
Homepage.Views.dll
Homepage.Views.pdb
HtmlAgilityPack.dll
Program.cs
README.md
Startup.cs
System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll
System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument.dll
web.config`

I assumed that Azure is supposed to pull the code from GitHub and build it the same way as I build it with `dotnet publish -c Release` command.

But it doesn't happen, looks like it just copies the files.

What is also weird is that my app still works after I hard refresh with Ctrl+F5. Hmmm...

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: How is your YAML build pipeline set up?

Comment: I used "App Service build service". Not a good choice? Should I use a different provider: GitHub Actions (Preview) or Azure Pipelines (Preview)?

Comment: You need to define your build pipeline and actually execute `dotnet publish` somewhere.